# Why won't these jQuery objects work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have some links in a navbar set off an event in jQuery.

HTML code for the body:

```
<body>
    <div id="bodydiv">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                <li id="#linkabout"><span>About</span></li>
                <li id="#linkservices"><span>Services</span></li>
                <li id="#linkportfolio"><span>Portfolio</span></li>
                <li id="#linknews"><span>News</span></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="middleAbout">
        </div>
        <div id="middleServices">
        </div>
        <div id="middlePortfolio">
        </div>
        <div id="middleNews">
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('span').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 0.75);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 1);
    });

    $('#linkServices').click(function(){
        $('#middleAbout').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
        $('#middleServices').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });

    $('#linkPortfolio').click(function(){
        $('#middleServices').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
        $('#middlePortfolio').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });

    $('#linkNews').hover(function(){
        $('#middlePortfolio').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
        $('#middleNews').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });

    $('#linkAbout').click(function(){
        $('#middleNews').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
        $('#middleAbout').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });
});
```

And finally, here is a link to the website to describe what I can't in words:
http://www.darcain.com

I want to have each item in the navbar link to a div, which will slide in gracefully when the appropriate div is clicked. At the moment, they are just pretty colours.

When I change the jQuery object that needs to be clicked to the div itself, it works fine, but with the navbar links, it doesn't work at all.

I hope that made sense.

Comment: you don't include the `#` sign for the ids. it should be `id="linkServices"`, etc.

Comment: yeah that stuff has to line up. Your trying to hit "linkServices" but your element id is "linkservices"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the '#' sign out of your 'id' parameter values.  JQuery needs the '#' symbol to know that it's looking for a dom element with the 'ID' parameter of the same value as the preceding name supplied by you, but you don't add the '#' to the id parameter value.  Should look like this.

```
        <li id="linkabout"><span>About</span></li>
        <li id="linkservices"><span>Services</span></li>
        <li id="linkportfolio"><span>Portfolio</span></li>
        <li id="linknews"><span>News</span></li>
```

Comment: Oh god, of course. I feel like an idiot now. Thanks :)
I also had to add a bit to the jQuery so it would make sure that all of the other divs were being hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Don't including the "#" in your id of attribute of the li tag. And care about the Case-Sensitive

```
            <ul>
            <li id="linkAbout"><span>About</span></li>
            <li id="linkServices"><span>Services</span></li>
            <li id="linkPortfolio"><span>Portfolio</span></li>
            <li id="linkNews"><span>News</span></li>
            </ul>
```